# input value change in real time, Natvie JS

Tags: javascript, html, input, real-time

I have 2 input with the class name `.ValueNextYear` who must have always the same value. The probleme is that, it don't have the same value in real time.

When I edit the first `.ValueNextYear` input who have 150 in value the second input ValueNextYear must have the same value but is not. If I enter 15000 in the first input ValueNextYear  the second contain 1500.

Also for calculate the value of `#EstimateAmountReceived` input I need to have a real value in `.ValueNextYear` for have a good result.

(Look on `NextYear()` function)

Any help is welcome. 
Sorry for my bad english

[Link with code](https://codepen.io/florianafm/pen/gdEmWZ)

```js
var AmountNextYear = (value1, value2) => {
 if (value1 >= 1 && value1 < 20) {
  return value2 += 10;
 } else if (value1 >= 20 && value1 < 50) {
  return value2 += 20;
 } else if (value1 >= 50 && value1 < 80) {
  return value2 += 30;
 } else if (value1 >= 80 && value1 < 100) {
  return value2 += 40;
 } else if (value1 >= 100 && value1 < 150) {
  return value2 += 50;
 } else if (value1 >= 150 && value1 < 300) {
  return value2 += 60;
 } else {
  return value2;
 }
};
var RealPaid = (value) => {
 let RealPaidValue = value - value * 66 / 100;
 return parseFloat(RealPaidValue).toFixed(2);
};
var TaxDeduction = (value) => {
 let TaxDeductionValue = value * 66 / 100;
 return parseFloat(TaxDeductionValue).toFixed(2);
};
var DownPayment = (value) => {
 let DownPayment = value * 60 / 100;
 return parseFloat(DownPayment).toFixed(2);
};
var DownPaymentInCompToLastYear = (value1, value2) => {
 let DownPaymentInCompToLastYear = value1 * 66 / 100 - value2;
 return parseFloat(DownPaymentInCompToLastYear).toFixed(2);
};
var checkSiEstIdentique = (ValueNextYear) => {
 if (ValueNextYear != document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear").value) {
  return ValueNextYear = document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear").value;
 }
};
var main = () => {
 var valueDonation = document.getElementById("valeurDon").value.replace(",", ".");
 document.getElementById("Deduction").value = TaxDeduction(valueDonation).replace(".", ",");
 var PostValueDonation = Math.ceil(valueDonation / 5) * 5;
 for (var i = document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear").length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[i].value = AmountNextYear(valueDonation, PostValueDonation);
 }
 var ValueNextYear = AmountNextYear(valueDonation, PostValueDonation);
 checkSiEstIdentique(document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[0].value);
 document.getElementById("DownPayment").value = DownPayment(TaxDeduction(valueDonation)).replace(".", ",");
 var DownPay = DownPayment(TaxDeduction(valueDonation));
 document.getElementById("EstimateAmountReceived").value = DownPaymentInCompToLastYear(ValueNextYear, DownPay).replace(".", ",");
 document.getElementById("formGroupExampleInput").value = TaxDeduction(ValueNextYear).replace(".", ",");
 document.getElementById("RealPaidValue").value = RealPaid(ValueNextYear).replace(".", ",");
 document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[0].addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  NextYear(DownPay);
 });
};
var NextYear = (DownPay) => {
 console.log("ValueNextYear", document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[0].value);
 document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[1].value = document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[0].value;
 console.log("EstimateAmountReceived", document.getElementById("EstimateAmountReceived").value);
 // document.getElementById("EstimateAmountReceived").value = DownPaymentInCompToLastYear(document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[0].value, DownPay )
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
 main()
});
```

```html
<div style="width: 80%; margin: auto;">
  <form>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">En 2017, vous avez donné :</label>
      <input type="text" class="" id="valeurDon" onkeyup="main()" value="100">
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Votre déduction fiscale sur votre don 2017</label>
      <input type="text" id="Deduction" disabled>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Pour un don 2018 de :</label>
      <input type="text" class="ValueNextYear">
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Vous recevrez un acompte des impôts en janvier 2019 de :</label>
      <input type="text" id="DownPayment" disabled>
    </div>

    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Vous percevrez en juillet 2019 un solde de :</label>
      <input type="text" id="EstimateAmountReceived" disabled>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Montant du don que vous souhaitez effectuer en 2018</label>
      <input type="text" class="ValueNextYear" disabled>
    </div>

    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Montant total de votre déduction fiscale 2018</label>
      <input type="text" id="formGroupExampleInput" disabled>
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Coût réel de vos dons 2018</label>
      <input type="text" id="RealPaidValue" disabled>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You've set up the event listener for the "keydown" event, but the value of the input field is not changed when that event fires. You'd be better off adding the handler for the "change" event.

Comment: Thank you, I told myself the same thing. But I do not see how. Do you have an example?

Comment: Just change "keydown" to "change".

Comment: Please keep in mind that `parseFloat(RealPaidValue).toFixed(2)` returns a string. Also you may want to use the "input" event.

Comment: I tried but when I change "keydown" to "change"  it doesn't work. When I add a new value it not detect that I press key and not change the value

Comment: @crg63 Please use the **input** event

Comment: If you talk about `onchange=""` event like this  `onchange="NextYear()"`  I think isn't possible beceause on my function NextYear I use argument who is variable from main

Comment: @enxaneta yes that's a good idea, my bad

Comment: @enxaneta  Ok yes sorry, I just figured out. It's work. :applose:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @enxaneta if I change `keydown` event by `input` event it works.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[0].addEventListener('input', function(event){
    NextYear(DownPay)
} );
```

And as pointed by @KENZiE it works too if I replace `keydown` event by `keyup` event.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[0].addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    NextYear(DownPay)
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `keydown` to `keyup`
In the main function, change:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[0].addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    NextYear(DownPay);
});
```

To:

```
    document.querySelectorAll(".ValueNextYear")[0].addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
    NextYear(DownPay);
});
```

See your code working here:
https://codepen.io/KenzDozz/pen/pOYdRx

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<input id="one" type="text" value="" onKeyUp="myFunction()">
<input id="two" type="text" value="" >

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("two").value = document.getElementById("one").value;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Abhi. But if I do this the argument of my function is undifined beceause I pass a variable from my main function.